# Swift 3 UI Tableview: dynamic cell height based on button text

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a custom tableview cell that contains 2 image views and several buttons.
Most of the items in the cell have a consistent size (height & width), but my main button displays text of a variable height. (The table displays user posts, and this button displays the the first 200 characters. But, the post may be <200 characters.)

The button has word wrap, so it may be 1 to several lines.

I've created the nib as 400, which is based on the required heights of the other items and estimated maximum for 200 characters for the post text button. I then return 400 as the `heightForRowAt`

But, while I'm happy that 4 lines of the full 200 characters looks fine, for posts with only 1 or 2 lines, there is far too much empty space. I would like to set the height of the cell dynamically based on the size of the button.

I added:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400
```

to the `viewDidLoad`, and

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
return tableView.rowHeight
```

to the `heightForRowAt` but that just turned the tableview into a complete mess!

How do I achieve this?

Comment: you sure, that you make all constraints correctly?

Comment: I wouldn't be 100% sure, since i'm a helluva newbie at iOS/Swift... but i think so, because when the post has the full 200 characters and displays all 4 lines, it looks fine. But I'd like to return a smaller button and cell if it's less than 4 lines. Can that be done via constraints?

Comment: i think this will help you http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/ and https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: thanks - I will check out the appcoda one. The Ray Wenderlich article is actually where I got the initial approach of using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` which didn't produce the result I was after.

Comment: hmmm... based on the appcoda article, probably I have an issue either in the constraints, or that I set the rowheight before the estimated height (per ray wenderlich). I shall check those later when I'm in front of my Mac. Alternatively, it may be the difference between a button and a label. Thanks for the links.